# Unit Testing - Identifying test scenarios

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, tdd

I'm new to unity testing and having a hard time identifying the correct scenarios to test.

Mainly I have following functions in my website(Using Laravel 5):

View Pages

1. Retrieve values from the DB using a model
2. Pass that data into the HTML template via a controller
3. Print data in HTML template to display

//view

```
public function getStudents(){

$students = Student::all(); // model: get all the students from Database
$data['students'] = $students;   
return view('views/students', $data);// Pass data into the view   

}
```

Edit/Create Pages

1. Retrieve input data from the view file
2. Validate
3. Save/Update DB and print success message.

   public function editStudent($id){

   ```
   //grab input data

   //validate

   //save in DB
   ```

   }

Above scenario looks pretty straight forward. As long as I get database entries
I get the success output. Invalid inputs can be filtered with validation (client/server sides). Do we need to write unit tests for above functions? What are the test scenarios?

Can you give me some practical examples to test?

This website mainly has 80% CRUD operations. Other than that I have:

1. Some functions to filter dates. ex: input date1, date2 - DB results will come within those two dates.
2. Some global functions. ex: format date time, currency. ACL functions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay In my opinion there is one scenario you need to test, what if retrieving from DB fails? You need to catch the exception in this case and show a proper error message. Then you need to test when the retrieving works as expected so the two scenarios are:

1st - Test when retrieving from the database fails.
2nd - Test when retrieving from the database succeeds, that the data are shown in the view. You can use this to test the 2nd scenario:

```
$this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel');
```

In my opinion, those two scenarios should be sufficient. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to my opinion You should unit test the controller function with view
you can mock the model for that. Reason for this is , these kind of functions oly check correct view is loading with given data

But for each edit and saving you have to write integration tests to check whether these data saving actually happening. you could use sqlite db for do integration tests if you don`t use native sql functions related to other databases